# Automake + libtool: pattern rule for per-object CFLAGS?

Tags: c, pattern-matching, gnu-make, automake, libtool

I'm using GNU Automake and libtool to compile my program. My `Makefile.am` looks like this:

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = \
    libObjectively.la

libObjectively_la_SOURCES = \
    Array.c \
    Class.c \
    Condition.c \
    Date.c \
    DateFormatter.c \
    Dictionary.c \
    Lock.c \
    Log.c \
    Object.c \
    String.c \
    Thread.c

libObjectively_la_CFLAGS = \
    -I ..

libObjectively_la_LDFLAGS = \
    -pthread \
    -shared
```

Everything compiles just fine. However, I would *like* to set `CFLAGS` for each source file using a pattern rule as well. In regular old `Makefile` syntax, this would look something like:

```
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -D__Class=$(subst .o,,$@) -o $@ $<
```

Is there a way to do this with Automake + libtool?

Comment: You mean you want to add `-D__Class=$(subst .0,,$@)` to the normal pattern rule?

Comment: I mean I'd like to have some equivalent of that pattern rule in an Automake-compatible way that jives with libtool. The pattern rule I posted was merely an example of how it might look in a GNU Makefile -- NOT an Automake Makefile.am.

Comment: Right, but I was trying to understand what part of that you were seeking to actually add yourself. The autotools just create makefiles that make uses. Which means the built-in rules are still there, etc. So the question was is that `-D` argument what you are trying to add the the default rule that builds `.o` files or was it something else about that line?

Comment: Gotcha. So that's the $10,000 question: can I inject a pattern rule that will hijack or augment libtool's compilation step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, there is no portable way to do this sort of thing.